# ActiveRecord/SQL: Complex DB query (outer_join / union / ?)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

DB query: I would like to get ONE database query with all participants of a training, showing all participants names and whether they already have this *one specific* skill. For building the result table (see sample) I would like to loop over the query result, without having to make a sub query for each employee.

```
|participant name|has_this_one_specific_skill|
|John Doe        |          yes              |
|Alex Hardacre   |          yes              |
|Abi Underwood   |          no               |
|Kevin Wallace   |          yes              |
|Connor Murray   |          no               |
```

Here is my DB structure. How would such a structure look like? Is this a left_outer_join or do I go with union?

[image]

Comment: It would be left outer joins with skills table via employees_skills table. But first tell me one thing when you say ` whether they already have a certain skill` , do you mean you want to only check for specific single skill ? i-e Enlist all the employees wether they have MYSQL skill or not (given MYSQL skill is there in skills table)

Comment: @QaisarNadeem: Correct. I only want to check for a specific skill. Employees can have many skills. What I want to show, does the employee already have the skill which is 'trained' in the training

Comment: You Participant class does not look right, I think what you mean is as follow: 
Its a bridge table between employees & trainings right? if yes then it should have 
`belongs_to :employee` & `belongs_to :training` ??

Comment: @QaisarNadeem: Yes, of course. Sorry error in copy & past. Will update.

Comment: Okay great, I'll write a query for you. Just confirm what's your database , Is it MYSQL or POSTGRESQL?

Comment: also what's rails version ?

Comment: DB is PostgresSQL. @QaisarNadeem: A query - oh mann! I would really appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :participants
  has_many :trainings,through: :participants
  has_many :trained_skills,through: :trainings,source: :skill
end



class Training < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :skill
end


class Participant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :training
  belongs_to :employee
end
```

**Solution 1** - Recommended

```
   Employee.left_joins(:trained_skills).where({skills: {name: ["MYSQL",nil]}}).pluck "employees.name,CASE WHEN skills.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'yes' else 'no' end"
```

Note: You can use `select` instead of `pluck` if you need Employees Objects. ie `######.select "employees.name as participant_name,CASE WHEN skills.id THEN 'yes' else 'no' end as has_this_one_specific_skill"`

**Solution 2**

```
 Employee.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN participants
  ON participants.employee_id = employees.id LEFT OUTER JOIN trainings
  ON trainings.id = participants.training_id LEFT OUTER JOIN skills
  ON skills.id = trainings.skill_id AND skills.name = 'MYSQL'").
  pluck "employees.name,CASE WHEN skills.id IS NOT NULL THEN 'yes' else 'no' end"
```

Comment: An almost plug & play solution. For the pluck I got an "PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of CASE/WHEN must be type boolean, not type bigint". Had to change to the following: "... CASE WHEN skills.id IS NOT NULL ... ". Do you want ot update?

Comment: Regarding soltuion 1, this actually only returns the employees who already have the skill, but not any which don't have the skill. Check out the SQL ActiveRecord generates: SELECT * FROM "employees" INNER JOIN "participants" ON "employees"."id" = "participants"."employee_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "employee_skills" ON "employee_skills"."employee_id" = "employees"."id" WHERE "participants"."training_id" = $1 AND ("employee_skills"."skill_id" IN (1,4) OR "employee_skills"."skill_id" IS NULL. As you will notice, it'a a bit different to solution 2, which delivers the desired result!